# How do I find lost folders

Tags: directory

Somehow (I don't know how) I seem to have lost my Documents file. I thought I'd look in the Trash but that now just seems to open my Home folder. What might have happened? I've searched for files looking for them but to no avail. What should I do? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When did you notice that your folder was deleted? I mean, after a command executed in terminal or after some installation? Depending of what you've ran, you'll need a program to restore those files (if it wasn't overwrite yet).

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + t) and type `locate Documents`. Maybe you moved the folder by mistake.

Comment: I you do this, remember to force an update on the db by running `sudo updatedb` before running the `locate`command as the db only updates every day or so and may not be current.